# JPA: reason for collection-member syntax?

Tags: jpa, collections

From JPA spec:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o
FROM Order o JOIN o.lineItems l
WHERE l.product.productType = ‘office_supplies’
```

can equivalently be expressed as follows, using the IN operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o
FROM Order o, IN(o.lineItems) l
WHERE l.product.productType = ‘office_supplies’
```

`IN(o.lineItems) l` does not add new features and does not look natural as JOIN. What is the reason for the collection-member syntax?

What is the corresponding Criteria API for `IN(o.lineItems) l`?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit please?

Comment: What is the corresponding Criteria API for IN(o.lineItems) l syntax in from clause?

Comment: I'd guess that the reason is to make communication with the database more OOP-likely